# Some FTP folders not visible to client

Tags: ftp, sftp

I ran into a very interesting issue today.

In my directory I have:

- hearts
- laptops
- pets
- scaledBU
- spotlights

Each of those are directories. I created these directories using FileZilla but they are not visible when I FTP into the server.

The only visible directories are:

- hearts
- laptops

These directories are not visible VIA FTP

- pets
- scaledBU
- spotlights

I can put in the absolute path and I can gain access and manage the content in these directories.

The permissions are the same for all the files. They are assigned to the correct user and group.  I just tried deleting the directories and re-creating the directories and the same issue occurs. I even tried renaming the directories and they still do not show. When logged into cPanel and using their FTP client I am able to see the directories.

Does anyone know what would cause this or a possible solution? I have checked Google but nothing seemed to work as of yet.

I even ran a `sudo chown -R user:group ~/direcotry/` to attempt to fix any permission issues but no change. The folders are not set to be hidden.